# how to increase increase timeout of phpmyadmin

Tags: amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin, timeout, maximize

I edited my file in `/var/www/html/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['LoginCookieValidity'] = 28800;` thats 8hours

already used `sudo service httpd restart`

but still, it expires in 30mins. why?

I'm using Amazon ec2 Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is because of your webserver setting for `session.gc_maxlifetime` being less than the LoginCookieValidity, which is causing the session to become invalid and removed.

From [the manual](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_LoginCookieValidity):

> Please note that php configuration option `session.gc_maxlifetime` might limit session validity and if the session is lost, the login cookie is also invalidated. So it is a good idea to set `session.gc_maxlifetime` at least to the same value of `$cfg['LoginCookieValidity']`.